# Headset output leaking into microphone input

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, sound-card

I can hear completely fine from my headset, but the microphone plays what comes out of my headphones, not what I'm saying into the microphone.

I'm on Windows 10, and I'm using a Turtle Beach Atlas One, so there is no software specifically for the headset. I am using the 3.5mm jacks on the front of my PC with the splitter cable.

These are my sound controllers:

[image: sound controllers - screenshot]

I am using Discord, OBS, and Windows Sound settings to test the microphone.
In settings, both the output and input device are set to the headset.

Comment: You may want to update your question, it is not entirely clear what you mean by 'the microphone is only playing the output sounds'. Did you select the correct input device (See the Windows configuration window → System → Sound, there's also a Test Microphone option here)? What software are you testing the microphone with?

Comment: *"In settings, both the output and input device are set to the headset."* - If you want Windows to listen to your microphone, you should set that as your audio input. If your PC has separate mic and headphone/speaker jacks, you should probably be using the splitter cable as suggested in the [official documentation](https://support.turtlebeach.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009645753-Atlas-One-Quick-Start-Guide) for the Altas One.

Comment: I have been using the splitter cable